# Does a sql concat function exist to create a delimited string

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Does a t-sql function exist to `concat` strings on a set delimiter similar to the example below?

```
DECLARE @value1 VARCHAR(20) = 'a'
DECLARE @value2 VARCHAR(20) = 'b'
DECLARE @value3 VARCHAR(20) = 'c'
DECLARE @value4 VARCHAR(20) = 'd'

SET @concatString = Join(",", @value1, @value2, @value3, @value4)
PRINT @concatString
```

I want have a result like this

```
-- prints "a,b,c,d"
```

Comment: You could use CONCAT(): http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx

Or you could possibly just roll your own: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx

Comment: Are you wanting to concat rows into a delimited string?

Answer (score 0):

In  SQL Server 2012 you can use this :

```
DECLARE @value1 VARCHAR(20) = 'a'
DECLARE @value2 VARCHAR(20)= 'b'
DECLARE @value3 VARCHAR(20)= 'c'
DECLARE @value4 VARCHAR(20)= 'd'

SELECT  CONCAT(@value1,',' ,@value2,',', @value3,',', @value4) AS ConcatResult
```